# Enable & disable authorization attribute based on config setting in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Is there a way to enable and disable authorization requirements (using authorize attribute) based on config setting?
Basically I want to decorate controller with `[Authorize]` attribute, but I want to have an option to disable it from config (so no code changes are needed).

I tried to look at `AuthorizationHandler`, but it looks like it builds on top of the authorize attribute, in the sense that it first checks that user is authorized, and then passes execution to my code:

```
namespace MeasureThat.Net.Logic.Web
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class to replace unconditional authorization attribute
    /// Will allow to disable authorize attribute from config
    /// </summary>
    public class ConfigurableAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ConfigurableAuthorizationRequirement>
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager;

        public ConfigurableAuthorizationHandler(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
            ConfigurableAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
        {
            if (requirement.AllowGuestsToCreateBenchmarks)
            {
                // No further checks need, guests can proceed
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else
            {
                // Need to make sure that user authenticated
                if (!signInManager.IsSignedIn(context.User))
                {
                    // Reject, not signed in
                    context.Fail();
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can customize AuthorizeAttribute and decorate controllers with [CustomAuthorize] instead.

Comment: @HarryNinh: That's not going to work and even if, subclassing AuthroizeAttribute is discouraged. The way its intended to be used by the ASP.NET Core team is to use Requirements for it